# Remove indexes before insertions and then rollback indexes

Tags: postgresql, rollback, bulk, postgresql-12

I wanna create bulk. I have script:

```sql
drop index idx_1;
drop index idx_2;
drop index idx_3;

COPY games FROM '/usr/share/nginx/html/var/dumps/games#1000000.sql' DELIMITER ',';
```

So, I wanna drop indexes, make insertions and then rollback my indexes. (I think it is simpliest than recreating it back by "manually".)

I tried it with savepoints but failed: it doing rollback before or with inserts although I need rollback after inserts for indexes only.

How can I solve this problem? Thx

Comment: If you rollback after the COPY, you will rollback the inserts done by the COPY statement as well. The only way to do this, is to re-create the indexes afterwards.

Comment: I know it. But how I can do it best? This indexes managed by Doctrine, but it don't restore some indexes after update - only after recreating table

Comment: You didn't drop them through Doctrine, why would you recreate them through Doctrine?

Comment: My hope was Doctrine will recreate my indexes. But it does recreate nothing indexes but id